# Check if object is all painted

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite

I have a brown sprite, which contains a hole with triangular shape.

I've added a trail renderer (and set its order in layer to appear behind the sprite), so the user can paint the sprite's hole without painting the sprite itself.

My question is: **how can it detect when the hole is all painted?**

I thought about using a shader to check if there is any black pixel in the screen, but I don't know if it's possible, because the shader won't know in what percentage of the image it is.

[image]

Comment: could you not check the material of the inner triangle and check its alpha value and so determine if it has colour

Comment: this doesn’t seem to be possible in this specific situation...

Comment: honestly, you probably wouldn't do that with a trail renderer, Daniel.  just search for some "painting on a sprite" type packages, and it will be easy enough for you!

Comment: then you simply check if that new image is "all filled in"

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Fattie, I'll look that.

Comment: really sorry I don't have time to give a full answer.  suggest search my many unity answers, there may be something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to take a screenshot with the [`ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture.html) method and then loop through an array of pixel colors from [`Texture2D.GetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html). You could then check if the array contains 'black' pixels.

I would do it in a coroutine for better performance as doing it every frame may slow down your application. Also what is important when it comes to CaptureScreenshotAsTexture according to unity docs:

> To get a reliable output from this method you must make sure it is called once the frame rendering has ended, and not during the rendering process. A simple way of ensuring this is to call it from a coroutine that yields on WaitForEndOfFrame. If you call this method during the rendering process you will get unpredictable and undefined results.

Comment: this is honestly not a great way to do it guys.  first of all, really, you don't use a trail renderer here!!!

Comment: Honestly I don't know if I'm using this or not, because I had an idea on how to solve that problem using a shader, but it seems a solid solution to me, even it might be slow. I don't need to check it every frame, so this is a good plan if the other options go wrong.

Comment: I agree this is not a perfect solution but the first thing that came to my mind. I assume Daniel has a reason to use trail renderer. Anyway hope it helps.